# Confused on Index Slicing in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-slicing

I am slicing my hour column and when I use slice(1, 3) and slice(0, 3) I get the same results. What am i missing? See in the image below.

[image: Original Column]

[image: slice(0, 3)]

[image: slice(1, 3)]

Comment: Please, no photos of code, just code.

Comment: Post a working example we can copy - including initializing the dataframe. Its best if its a small demonstration dataset. We don't need a dozen columns and who knows how many rows when the question regards a few columns.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide data for [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: And include `dataset.dtypes`. If `02:00:00` is a string and you slice it to 0:3, you get `"02:"` which would fail when initializing an `int`. `dataset["hour"].str.sllice(0,3)` would be interesting to see what happens there.

Comment: My guess is there's a space at the beginning of `dataset["hour"]`. So `slice(0, 3)` is `" 02"` while `slice(1, 3)` is `"02"`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. And yes, you are right. There is indeed a space at the beginning. So, I didn't notice it. Also, can you guide me how to mark this as an answer because it is in a comment section and not answer section Sorry I'm new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space at the beginning of `dataset["hour"]`.

So `slice(0, 3)` is " 02" while `slice(1, 3)` is "02".

This was answered by @Barmar on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64328686/confused-on-index-slicing-in-python/64346221#comment113752928_64328686).

Answer (score 1):

If it's needed to extract an hour from the time, it probably would be better to use:

```
dataset['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['hour'],format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.hour
```